# Can't resolve Invalid Hook Call error (in conjunction with React Router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having an issue with rendering components. I get an 'Invalid Hook call' error in my console. I've tried to check for the three main 'causes' as per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call), but I can't seem to find what it is. I'm using React Router and trying to set up the skeleton for my website. [Full repository](https://github.com/YinChuRijnaard/vi-website). (Before installing (and setting up) React Router, everything worked just fine...)

No duplicate React as far as I can tell: [image: After running npm ls react]

Here's my `Header.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Over } from "../../pages/Over";
import { Partners } from "../../pages/Partners";
import { Contact } from "../../pages/Contact";
import { NavBar } from "./Header.styled";

export const Header = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen((prevIsOpen) => !prevIsOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar>
        <nav className="navBar">
          <button onClick={handleToggle}>{isOpen ? "Close" : "Open"}</button>
          <ul className={`menuNav ${isOpen ? " showMenu" : ""}`}>
            <li>
              <Link to="/over">Over</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/partners">Partners</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Routes>
            <Route path="over" element={<Over />} />
            <Route path="partners" element={<Partners />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          </Routes>
        </nav>
      </NavBar>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here's my `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { App } from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked your repository and couldn't find react-router-dom in your package.json file. Maybe you installed it in a different directory, so reinstalling it in the root level (where your package.json) is located is should solve the issue.

Comment: thank you! A solution so simple, embarrassing much. Completely overlooked the fact I could've installed it in a different directory. Thank you.